# Is there a way to execute distributed code in Python on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, distributed-computing

I created a scraper in Python that is navigating a website. It pulls many links and then It has to visit every link pull the data and parse and store the result.

Is there an **easy** way to run that script distributed in the cloud (like AWS)?

Ideally, I would like something like this (probably is more difficult, but just to give an idea)

```
run_in_the_cloud --number-of-instances 5 scraper.py
```

after the process is done, the instances are killed, so it does not cost more money.

I remember I was doing something similar with [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop) and [java](/questions/tagged/java) with [mapreduce](/questions/tagged/mapreduce) long time ago.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a separate Amazon EC2 instance for each scraper. You could run multiple copies of the scraper on the one computer, depending upon the amount of RAM, CPU and network bandwidth. I would suggest you experiment with running multiple apps (or simply multiple threads) on one computer before spreading out to multiple computers. There are tools like [Scrapy | A Fast and Powerful Scraping and Web Crawling Framework](https://scrapy.org/) that can handle multi-thread scraping for you, but if you wanted to deploy across multiple EC2 instances you'd have to build that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your scraper in a docker image it's relatively trivial to run and scale dockerized applications using [AWS ECS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). Just create a task definition and point it at your container registry, then submit runTask requests for however many instances you want. [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) is another tool you could use to trivially parallelize container instances too.